# TFS Build Copy to Versioned Folder

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm currently looking at a TFS build server setup & I was trying to set up a process whereby I can set up a build template to build to a folder based on the version number of a .NET assembly that's part of the build (As per the assemblyinfo.cs file). I've got it building to the standard looking folder ("Release_20130502.1"), but that's not exactly useful in 4 months time when we want to find the build for the v1.1.0 release.

Basically I want to make a special build template which will create a major release, and I'd like the folders it makes to be more noticable as versions rather than timestamps. I'm also hoping to automatically label the release as that version too. I know how to copy the files & make labels, but I'm not sure how to get at the version numbers.

I'd also love if I could get this into the Build Name recorded in TFS somehow but I suspect that might be a bit optimistic.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this (Or alternatively any other technique that'll get me easily recognizable release version builds)?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms181716.aspx - Step 7 - set your drop folder name

Comment: Aye, I've seen that part, the tricky part is getting my hands on the assembly version so I can use it in the substitution to put together the drop folder path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at build number format property for build definitions this is used to generate the build number and in turn the build folder during build and label in sourcecontrol if its enabled, you can modify this manualy to pass desired build number. The mentioned drop folder can be manually given as well. And you can always copy the folder after build by hand.

You can use revision variable to create something that works similiar to what you want, Revision number gets incremented if there is build with same name in system

Format: Release v1.$(Rev).0 - this would give you Release v1.1.0, Release v1.2.0, ... on each build

You will have to customize build definition with custom activity for your defined goal to work without manual interaction. However with details you have provided this approach has issues - each project has its own assembly info - which one do you use, what if they are different? This should get you started.

http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/04/20/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-1-Introduction.aspx

You can take a look at these may find something useful
http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/

It all comes down how often do these build take place, if its week or more then doing it by hand is perfecly valid aproach in my book.

Comment: Aye, it's possible we'll have to make it manual but I'd really prefer if I can avoid that cause part of my goal is to make sure every release is built identically for repeatability. It's more about reducing the chance of mistakes than automation (though that's a plus too).

As far as determining which dll I care about, I can easily do that via our naming conventions & could define the path to the DLL in terms of the variables already available to me in the build.

I'll take a look at those custom activities. It may turn out manual's my only choice, but I wanted to be sure before I gave up.

Comment: That link has it - http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/05/13/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-5-Increase-AssemblyVersion.aspx + http://www.ewaldhofman.nl/post/2010/06/01/Customize-Team-Build-2010-e28093-Part-10-Include-Version-Number-in-the-Build-Number.aspx